# css box inset not showing when changed from href to data-href

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this css and html that is a bootstrap nav menu

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a href="#slider" class="scroll">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            About<span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="about-music-therapy.html#services" data-href="#services">Vibe Music Therapy</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-music-therapy.html#portfolio" data-href="#portfolio">What is Music Therapy?</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-music-therapy.html#team">Who Benefits?</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-music-therapy.html#contact">Partner and Affliates</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Services<span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="about-music-therapy.html#team">Music Therapy</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-music-therapy.html#portfolio">Training/CPD/Workshops</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-music-therapy.html#contact">Volunteer Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a data-href="#portfolio" class="scroll">Clips/Vignettes</a></li>
            <li><a data-href="#testimonials" class="scroll">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team" class="scroll">Evidence</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cost" class="scroll">Cost</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog" class="scroll">Blog</a></li>

   </ul>
```

And the css for the underscore that moves with each menu option is as follows ...

```css
.navbar-nav {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff;
}
.navbar-nav > li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 green;
}
.navbar-nav > li.active > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

the problem is when i change the a href to a data-href (which is needed for some js code to execute a scroll function) the box-inset bit disappears.   Any takers for this ? Thanks in advance.

this is the js for the scroll function btw , it doesn't work if i cahnge data-href to href so not sure how to get aruond this one tbh...

```
  var scroll_duration = 1000;

        if (self.$win.width()>767) {
            $('.navbar-nav a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').each(function(){
                addEvent($(this)[0], 'click', function(e) {
                    var t = e.target,
                        body = $("html, body");
                    if (t.hasAttribute('data-href')) {
                        var sT = $('section' + t.getAttribute('data-href'))[0]
                                .offsetTop-164-86/2-10-0;
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: sT
                        }, scroll_duration, 'swing');
                    }
                }, false);
            });
            $('head').append($('<style>').html('.navbar-nav a{cursor:pointer;}'));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Don't change `href` to `data-href`, as if you do you loose the link. Have both or tell your script to look for `href`

Comment: i agree with you but have already changed the instances of 'data-href' in the code to 'href' and it just makes the function not work

Comment: The links that has `data-href`, how can anyone click on those? ... and you need to check  your css for a `href`attribute selector

Comment: there is none, this a bootsrap navbar as mentioned

Comment: Try both `href` and `data-href` ... and anchors without `href` attribute will not validate properly

Comment: if i add data-href to the anchors it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103847/discussion-between-havingagoatit-and-lgson).